# DejaDup - Clearing settings due to backup troubles

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup, deja-dup

**The Problem**

I'm using Deja Dup to back up my recently restored and upgraded Ubuntu 11.10 machine. However, only one backup has ever succeeded; in every subsequent backup, I was continually asked for my encryption password. It turns out that this is a [previously fixed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/681002) and, as such, I reported it as having potentially regressed. While I wait for a fix, however, this leaves me with a broken backup program that I can't use. Because my system is somewhat unstable, I need this backup to work *now;* it's led me to look for workarounds.

**The Potential Workaround**

I've inferred from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53980/how-to-delete-all-the-settings-for-an-uninstalled-program) that I can clear the settings for duplicity and Deja Dup by eliminating `~/.cache/duplicity` and/or `~/.cache/deja-dup` and my old backups. This will allow me to change the settings that are (supposedly) causing the bug and let me do backups normally.

**Why I Need Your Help**

To make the workaround work, I need to delete my old backups. My old backups are stored on the Ubuntu One cloud. However, I can't figure how to delete files as there isn't a local copy. I know that there is an [API](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/files/store_files/cloud/#delete_apifile_storagev1pathtovolumepathtonode) call to do this, but there must be a more elegant way to delete these files.

**Long Story Short...**

How can I delete files on Ubuntu One that have no local copy that can be manipulated?

Comment: For alternate backup solutions see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem . Why is your system unstable and can we help you fix the underlying problem ?

Comment: It's a hardware problem and has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Thank you for your concern, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete files from the Ubuntu One web interface, located at

https://one.ubuntu.com/files/

Click the "More" button on the far right

[image: More]

For details see [Ubuntu One Tutorial](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/install-and-setup-file-sync/)

Comment: You know, looking for a tutorial would make a lot of sense, haha. I don't know why I didn't think of it in the first place. Thank you!